# TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listen'

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

// Dependancies
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var events = require('events');
var cache = require('./plugins_cache.js');
var util = require('util');
var enocean = require('node-enocean')();


// Type de données
var enoceanRecords = {
    PTEC: { 'value': '', 'type': 'TEXT', 'unit': '' },
    IINST: { 'value': '', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'unit': 'A' }
};
// Includes
vm.runInThisContext(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/" + "plugins_table.js"));
var table = new Table();

// Class
var PluginEnocean = function () {
    this.infos = { name: "enocean",
   version: "0.0.1"
   };
};

PluginEnocean.prototype.query = function () {
    return this.infos;
}

PluginEnocean.prototype.init = function (config) {
  var options = config.get('plugin:enocean');
    var path = DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT;

    if(options !== undefined) {
        if(options['path'] !== undefined) {
            path = options['path'];
        }
    }

    // Open serial port
    console.log(path);
    enocean.listen(path);
 
 // Set table name
    table.setName(this.infos['name']);
 
  // Collect data
    enocean.on('data', function (data) {
  
   var uuid = data['senderId'] ;
    
   for(key in enoceanRecords) {
     
   table.setRecord(key, enoceanRecords[key]);
   }
    
    
    
    
 // Feed data
   if(uuid !== undefined) { 
    table.setUuid(uuid);
    table.setStamp();
    cache.push(table);
   }
    });
  
 
};

PluginEnocean.prototype.run = function () {
};

PluginEnocean.prototype.exit = function () {
};

var enocean = module.exports = new PluginEnocean();
```

[image: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listen']
Alguém tem uma ideia de que se trata precisamente?
Não consigo perceber a razão deste erro...

OBRIGADO.

Comment: Pode postar um pouco do código? Creio que isso tem a haver com a linha em que está a fazer listen a uma determinada porta. Mas sem só com isto não consigo chegar a uma conclusão

Comment: Bom dia Miguel, acabei de actualizar o post, e agradeço pelo HELP !

Comment: Eu acho que tem a haver com "/dev/ttyUSB0" . Nunca usei este pacote, mas pelo que percebo enocean não tem esse metodo `listen` disponínel, pelo menos quando o tenta usar

Comment: Estás a re-escrever a variável (!)... `var enocean = module.exports = new PluginEnocean();` e assim `var enocean = require('node-enocean')();` é apagado.

Comment: Obrigado pelos vossos comentarios, realmente estou grato...! Mas normalmente faço a leitura da porta serial "/dev/ttyUSB0", e quando faço teste tudo funciona perfeitamente ! O erro  so ocorre quando lanço o script principal "main.js", quando lanço simplesmente o " plugin_enocean.js" tudo passa bem !

Comment: @AndréPKA viste o meu comentário? estás a apagar o `require('node-enocean')();`...

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO ! Finalmente funcionou... Agradeço mais uma vez ! Estava re-escrevendo a variavel "enocean" assim como BEM disse o SERGIO !